# I have a saved a excel file to RDS file but unable to view the same since it shows no data

Tags: r

I have a excel file which i saved into #saveRDS format but now when am trying to view the same i get "no data available in the table"

```
countries_all2 <- saveRDS(countries_map, "as_countries_map_2019.RDS")
summary(countries_all2)

Length  Class   Mode 
     0   NULL   NULL 

readRDS(countries_all2)
```

> Error in readRDS(countries_all2) : bad 'file' argument

```
readRDS(countries_all2.RDS)
```

> Error in readRDS(countries_all2.RDS) : 
>     object 'countries_all2.RDS' not found

```
readRDS(as_countries_map_2019.RDS)
```

> Error in readRDS(as_countries_map_2019.RDS) : 
>     object 'as_countries_map_2019.RDS' not found

```
summary(countries_all2)
Length  Class   Mode 
     0   NULL   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not assign the result of `saveRDS` to the variable `countries_all2`.

```
saveRDS(countries_map, "as_countries_map_2019.RDS")
```

Then you need to quote the file name in `readRDS`. Assuming you want to read into the object `countries_all2`:

```
countries_all2 <- readRDS("as_countries_map_2019.RDS")
```

Comment: Please accept and vote for the answer if it solved your problem.